# Why is Google search not using QUIC?

Tags: google-chrome, google-search, quic

I saw Google search set the `alt-svc` header, with QUIC version 39 in header string.

`alt-svc: hq=":443"; ma=2592000; quic=51303431; quic=51303339; quic=51303338; quic=51303337; quic=51303335,quic=":443"; ma=2592000; v="41,39,38,37,35"`

I'm using Google Chrome Canary which supported QUIC 39. But when I open Google, it still working on HTTP/2 and not on QUIC + HTTP/2.

I set the `alt-svc` header with QUIC for my website, and it worked.

`alt-svc: quic=":443"; ma=7776000; v="39"; persist=1`

So I confirm my browser is fine, but what's wrong with Google search?

Answer (score 0):

Chrome is still an opt-in feature. Is it enabled in chrome://flags `enable-quic` ?

Comment: Yes, I enabled it, but still not working. It seems like Google Chrome Canary doesn't support `hq` in `alt-svc` header.